# What will happen to my data if I change a constraint in my domain knowing that all of my data doesn't satisfy that constraint?

Tags: grails, constraints

I am a relatively new to using Grails and I am working on a fairly large platform that has been running for a few years.

I want to change one of the fields in one of my domain classes to no longer be nullable.

What will happen to the data that currently exists that doesn't satisfy that constraint?

Help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: If it makes sense for your app, consider a SQL script to update existing records prior to deploying the new version of the app. That way the data will be ready for the constraint and you won't have to add code to handle old records; code that may eventually become obsolete as records are updated.

Comment: Emmanuel, that is a good idea. I didn't think about how that code will be obsolete after I create that constraint. I will look into how I can update the data now to satisfy the constraint before I actually implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fetch these newly invalid objects, but calls to `save()` will result in a non-save or `save(failOnError: true)` will result in a `ValidationException`.

Depending on your needs and what the field represents, you could set the field to something for all existing nulls or more complicated (but maybe more useful) - write a custom constraint validator for the particular field that allows objects that have already been persisted to retain the null but throw an exception for newly saved instances with the field null.

** Validator Approach **

I haven't tested this, but I think something *like* this would be a way to go for the constraint validator.  It's possible that the logic could be reduced and/or I haven't caught edge cases but it's worth trying.

```
Integer someField

someField validator: { val, obj ->
    // new objects must have a non-null
    if(!obj.id) {
        return val != null
    } else {
        // if field has changed and changed to null
        if (obj.isDirty('someField') && val == null) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, I added some more to the answer to elaborate on the validator part.